# MySql optimization / speed that's been haunting me

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference between

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

and

```
SELECT my_column_id FROM my_table
```

where:

1. `my_table` has million(s) of rows
2. there are a lot of concurrent users doing sql queries on the website

in speed? Is it better to `SELECT` just 1 column instead of * (all) for a `rowCount()` query?

Comment: Is it the speed of the `SELECT` statement that is problematic, or the fetch loop that is slow?  And are you not using any `WHERE` clause, constantly selecting millions of rows?

Comment: If all you need is row count, why not just do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table`?

Comment: ...than what is the difference between SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT COUNT(my_column) ? I know the latter is a valid MySql command

Comment: + in my code there is a file that doesn't return me the row count with fetchColumn on SELECT COUNT(*) but in all other places it works. i will investigate further. but i stumbled upon rowCount() function which does exactly return the number of rows in the latest db->query. I think rowCount is faster than do 1 query for row count and then 1 query for the actual returning of column / row values

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I do use WHERE clause, but sometimes I need the whole table row count...i was wondering if the query will be optimised when doing SELECT COUNT(my_column) and not SELECT COUNT(*) in loading less stuff in RAM and maybe being faster in not selecting internally all columns somehow....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course theres a difference.

`SELECT * FROM my_table` - Select all column's worth of data (whole table).

`SELECT my_column_id FROM my_table` - Select one column's worth of data.

Its common sense really.. More data.. More time.

But @Juhana makes a good point. If your just counting rows, use `SELECT COUNT(*)`

**For the sake of your comment....**

```
O--O-------------O-------------O
|ID|   my_col_1  |   my_col_2  |
O--O-------------O-------------O
|0 | fskdjfh     | jfkhgdkfj   |
|1 | NULL        | hfkjsdh     |
|2 | jfkdhsdkjh  | NULL        |
|3 | fdfhkjh     | NULL        |
|4 | NULL        | NULL        |
O--O-------------O-------------O
```

`SELECT COUNT(my_col_1)` will return 3

`SELECT COUNT(my_col_2)` will return 2

`SELECT COUNT(*)` will return 4

Comment: k, but then why is it possible to do SELECT COUNT(*) and then SELECT COUNT(my_column) ... what's the difference ?

Comment: Some columns may have `NULL` on a row where other columns have values. `SELECT COUNT(*)` counts all rows where at least one column has data, `SELECT COUNT(my_column)` will skip rows equal to `NULL`. Does this make sense?

Comment: definitely :) now i got it ! I knew it must be something like that, so if column has NULL values COUNT does not do them....COUNT(*) will do all columns (except where a ROW has all NULL values which afterall is not a valid row)...thanks man!!